# showing content in the same time in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Despite the fact I am total beginner in Angular I don't have a clue how to solve this issue the best. 
Imagine I have two users, who owe money to each other, user: 'A' and 'B'.

'A' have 5 transactions and has to pay 5000$ to 'B'. And 'B' has 50000 transactions and has to pay 100000$ to 'A'. On this moment I see 2 transactions instead of 1 and I have to do math in head. Code looks like this:

```
$scope.charges = {};

totalChargeUserToFactory.query({
    id: null
}).$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.charges.to = data;
});

totalChargeUserFromFactory.query({
    id: null
}).$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.charges.from = data;
});
```

So I just decided to change it on to solve my problem:

```
$scope.charges = {};

totalChargeUserToFactory.query({
    id: null
}).$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.charges.to = data;

    totalChargeUserFromFactory.query({
        id: null
    }).$promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.charges.from = data;

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.charges.to.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.charges.from.length; j++) {
                if ($scope.charges.to[i].userFromId === $scope.charges.from[j].userToId) {
                    if ($scope.charges.to[i].charge < $scope.charges.from[j].charge) {
                        $scope.charges.from[j].charge = (parseFloat($scope.charges.from[j].charge)
                        - parseFloat($scope.charges.to[i].charge)).toFixed(2);
                        $scope.charges.to.splice(i, 1);
                        i--;
                    } else {
                        $scope.charges.to[i].charge = (parseFloat($scope.charges.to[i].charge)
                        - parseFloat($scope.charges.from[j].charge)).toFixed(2);
                        $scope.charges.from.splice(j, 1);
                        j--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
});
```

And now the real problem occures. With so much transactions it takes time until the content will be loaded. When A has just being loaded, B is loading 2 seconds longer and just then appears on screen. It doesn't look good... Can you give me some tips how to avoid this? basing on this code? I will be appreciated.

I was looking on google to find the solution, but I could not find anything satysfying, which directly influence my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use you initial design and execute some code when both promises have been resolved with the help of [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

```
$scope.charges = {};

var q1 = totalChargeUserToFactory.query({
    id: null
}).$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.charges.to = data;
    return data;
});

var q2 = totalChargeUserFromFactory.query({
    id: null
}).$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.charges.from = data;
    return data;
});

$q.all([q1, q2]).then(function(data) {
    // do math here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use $q.all to wait until all of your api calls have completed before displaying anything.

```
$q.all([
  totalChargeUserToFactory.query({
    id: null
  }),
  totalChargeUserFromFactory.query({
        id: null
  })
]).then(function(values) {   
     $scope.charges.to = values[0];
     $scope.charges.from = values[1];
   });
```